# Handling gzipped content on Android

Tags: java, android, gzip

I'm trying to parse a file from the web on Android using the DOM method.

The code in question is:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.beatport.com/en-US/xml/content/home/detail/1/welcome_to_beatport");

    InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(is);
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Exception = " + e);
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
V/XMLParseTest1(  846):Exception = org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: name expected (position:START_TAG <null>@2:176 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43ea4538)
```

The file is being handed to me gzipped. I've checked the `is` object in the debugger and its length is 6733 bytes (the same as the content length of the file in the response headers) however if I save the file to my harddrive from the browser it's size is 59114 bytes. Furthermore if I upload it to my own server which doesn't gzip XML-s when it serves them and set the URL the code runs just fine.

I'm guessing that what happens is that Android tries to parse the gzipped stream.

Is there a way to first unzip the stream? Any other ideas?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/6717165/779408. A compress and decompress method is represented there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can wrap the result of `url.openStream()` in a [GZIPInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html). eg:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream()));
```

To auto-detect when to do this, use the Content-Encoding HTTP header. eg:

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
if ("gzip".equals(connection.getContentEncoding())) {
  stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream));
}
InputSource is = new InputSource(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question: is there a way to find out if a stream is gzipped?

Comment: `GZIPInputStream` throws an `ZipException` if your stream is not gziped. You may catch this exception and then open stream without using GZip.

Answer (score 3):

> By default, this implementation of HttpURLConnection requests that
>   servers use gzip compression. Since getContentLength() returns the
>   number of bytes transmitted, you cannot use that method to predict how
>   many bytes can be read from getInputStream(). Instead, read that
>   stream until it is exhausted: when read() returns -1. Gzip compression
>   can be disabled by setting the acceptable encodings in the request
>   header:
>
> urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");

so nothing need to do.